# Powershell - Finding Uninstall Strings and Executing

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm attempting to write a script that will be pushed to all domain computers to identify Adobe Registry Keys to and uninstall the ones for Adobe Flash via the corresponding Uninstall Strings.

I'm using the following to get any registry keys that are associate with Adobe:
`Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "Adobe"} | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString`

The above works as needed and pulls the Adobe Keys, but I don't want to run the UninstallString for all of them, just the ones for Adobe Flash Player.

I've tried the following to try to pull just the keys that contain "Adobe Flash Player" but I keep getting errors:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "Adobe" } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString |

Foreach-object{if ($_.GetValue('DisplayName') -like "Adobe Flash Player"){

$uninstall = $_.GetValue('UninstallString')

cmd /c $uninstall
}
}
```

[image: Method Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to avoid both `Get-ItemProperty` and `Select-Object`, because in order to be able to call `$_.GetValue(...)` in the `ForEach-Object` call at the end of your pipeline, you need the original [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey) instances output by `Get-ChildItem`:

```bash
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall,
              HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall |
  Where-Object { $_.GetValue('DisplayName') -match 'Adobe Flash Player' } | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    cmd /c $_.GetValue('UninstallString') 
  }
```

In your attempt, what `$_` contained in the `ForEach-Object` call was a `[pscustomobject]` instance, which doesn't have a `.GetValue()` method - that is what the error message is conveying.

Comment: This is very helpful but has raised a new question.  The above will run the installer but I can't get it to run silently even if I append ' /quiet' so I want to go the route of deleting the Registry Key completely.  If I want to iterate through the above ChildItem paths and assign the PSChildName and Name values to variables, how would I do that?  I've tried using 'foreach-object' and using 'select' and also '$_.GetValue' but neither will assign a value to the variables

Comment: @JPrentice, to delete the matching registry key(s), replace the `ForEach-Object` call with `Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf` `-WhatIf` _previews_ what will be deleted; remove it once you're sure that the right keys are being targeted.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for all the help!  ...I really need to skill up on Powershell

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @JPrentice; my pleasure.